# Filtering a Swift [AnyObject] array by type

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

Say I have an array of `AnyObject`.

```
let grabBag: [AnyObject] = [ "Tom", 4, "Dick", NSObject(), "Harry" ]
```

and I want to cast it to an array of `Strings`, extracting only those elements that are in fact `Strings`. I would expect this to work:

```
let strings = grabBag.filter{ $0 is String } as! [String]      // 1
```

but it gives the error `'Bool' is not convertible to 'String'`. Yet this works:

```
let definitelyStrings = grabBag.filter{ $0 is String }         // 2
let strings = definitelyStrings as! [String]                   //
```

Why does `2` work when `1` does not? And is there a simpler (than `2`) way of extracting and casting the elements of an `[AnyObject]` to whatever `[T]`?

Comment: In example 2 you don't need the second line: `let strings = grabBag.filter{ $0 is String }` is sufficient. No forced type casting. Prove it with `strings is [String]` which returns true

Comment: @vadian `let strings = grabBag.filter{ $0 is String }` returns `[AnyObject]` with OP's `grabBag` array, not `[String]`.

Comment: @EricD: But you can do `grabBag.filter{ $0 is String } .map{$0.lowercaseString }` which is normally not possible with `[AnyObject]`

Comment: @vadian, you certainly can do that with `[AnyObject]`. `let lc = grabBag.map{ $0.lowercaseString }`. It returns a `[String!]`. It mostly works because `[AnyObject]` in this context is implicitly mapped over to `NSArray`. You couldn't do this without importing Foundation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's better to use `compactMap` for a nice one-liner:

```
let strings = grabBag.compactMap { $0 as? String }
```

Now `strings` is of type `[String]`.

Answer (score 8):

This is what `flatMap` is for:

```
let strings = grabBag.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
```

This takes a closure that returns an optional; if the optional is non-nil, then it is added to the result.

(<strike>Note that this doesn't match the meaning of `flatMap` from other languages, and doesn't even match the other meaning of `flatMap` in Swift. A better name would have been `mapOptional` or `mapSome`. But it's still kind of intuitive, even if inconsistent. It "maps to optionals, then flattens out all the nils."</strike> Rob Mayoff notes that if Optionals were SequenceTypes, which they probably should be, this would be a sensible name.)

Comment: Scala's `flatMap` works with its `Option` the same way Swift's `flatMap` works with its `Optional`. But Scala gets it “for free” because Scala's `Option` is a full traversable-collection type (that contains either 0 or 1 elements). Sadly, Swift's `Optional` doesn't (currently) conform to `SequenceType`.

Comment: @robmayoff I misread Scala's signature. It's `flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]`. I thought it was `flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ List[List[B]]): List[B]`. OK; I'll buy that.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that test 1 failing is clearly a compiler bug. In fact it crashes in the REPL:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.1.100.2 700.1.74). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let grabBag: [AnyObject] = [ "Tom", 4, "Dick", NSObject(), "Harry" ]
grabBag: [AnyObject] = 5 values {
  [0] = "Tom"
  [1] = Int64(4)
  [2] = "Dick"
  [3] = {
    isa = NSObject
  }
  [4] = "Harry"
}
  3> let strings = grabBag.filter { $0 is String } as! String
strings: String = {
  _core = {
    _baseAddress =
    _countAndFlags =
    _owner = <extracting data from value failed>

  }
}
Execution interrupted. Enter Swift code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
4> :bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x501bac, 0x00000001005c41f4 $__lldb_expr12`main + 420 at repl.swift:3, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001005c41f4 $__lldb_expr12`main + 420 at repl.swift:3
    frame #1: 0x0000000100001420 repl_swift`_mh_execute_header + 5152
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8dd725c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8dd725c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Anyway, as Rob Napier also answered, `grabBag.flatMap { $0 as? String }` is shorter and maybe simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tiny Swift 5 Array extension based on ayaio's answer. Might be useful if you want to filter by type a lot and don't want to write a closure every time.

```
extension Array {
   func filteredByType<T> (_: T.Type) -> [T] {
       return compactMap({ (element) in
           return element as? T
       })
   }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let array: [Any] = ["foo", 47, ["baz"], "bar"]
let stringArray: [String] = array.filteredByType(String.self)
print(stringArray) // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: This extension of yours is a good idea but it will fail. Suppose I have a NSWindow and a NSWindow based class called `MyWindow`. All elements of `MyWindow` class will be considered `NSWindow` and the filter will not work.

Comment: Either I missed your point or I don't think I would consider that "failing". That's just how inheritance works. Consider: if you have `class Base {}` and `class Special: Base {}` in an array
`let array: [Any] = [Base(), Special()]`, and then filter that array by
`let baseItems = array.filteredByType(Base.self) // count 2` and 
`let specialItems = array.filteredByType(Special.self) // count 1`, I would say that's expected behavior for a type-based filter.

Comment: @Duck see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513949/7486818).

Answer (score 1):

Improved extension that works for any sequence:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func filter<T>(by: T.Type) -> [T] {
        compactMap{$0 as? T}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension to filter an Array by type:

```
extension Array {
    func filtered<T>(by _: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return filter { type(of: $0) == T.self } as! [T]
   }
}
```

Usage example:

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
view.addSubview(UILabel())
view.addSubview(UIImageView())
view.addSubview(UIView())

let allUIViewsInSubviews      = view.subviews.filtered(by: UIView.self)
let allUILabelsInSubviews     = view.subviews.filtered(by: UILabel.self)
let allUIImageViewsInSubviews = view.subviews.filtered(by: UIImageView.self)
print(allUIViewsInSubviews.count) // 2
print(allUILabelsInSubviews.count) // 1
print(allUIImageViewsInSubviews.count) // 1
```